# Postgresql - how to create a column if another column is positive for a specific data range

Tags: postgresql

I am new at PostgreSQL and learning day by day. I am using PostgreSQL 9.4.

I have daily data and would like to create a binary variable with value 1 if another variable (here, minimum flow) has been positive for **at least** 5 consecutive days.

The data has the following structure (“test” is the variable I would like to create):

```
Group_id    |    date        |    min_flow   |   test
------------+----------------+----------------------------
1          |  2012-02-01    | 0             |  0
1          |  2012-02-02    | 0             |  0
1          |  2012-02-03    | 1.5           |  1
1          |  2012-02-04    | 1             |  1
1          |  2012-02-05    | 0.7           |  1
1          |  2012-02-06    | 0.8           |  1
1          |  2012-02-07    | 1.2           |  1
1          |  2012-02-08    | 1.5           |  1
1          |  2012-02-09    | 0             |  0
1          |  2012-02-10    | 0             |  0
1          |  2012-02-11    | 0.9           |  0
1          |  2012-02-12    | 1.2           |  0
1          |  2012-02-13    | 0             |  0
1          |  2012-02-14    | 0             |  0
```

I have achieved this by using window function as follows:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN min_flow > 0                                
    AND                                        
    (
    -- current row + next 4 rows have a min(flow) > 0
    ((lead(min_flow, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0     
    AND (lead(min_flow, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0 
    AND (lead(min_flow, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0
    AND (lead(min_flow, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0)
    OR (
    -- current row – previous 4 rows have a min(flow) > 0
    (lag(min_flow, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0         
    AND (lag(min_flow, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0 
    AND (lag(min_flow, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0
    AND (lag(min_flow, 4) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0)
    OR (
    -- current row + next 3 rows – previous 1 row have a min(flow) > 0
    (lead(min_flow, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0         
    AND (lead(min_flow, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0 
    AND (lead(min_flow, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0
    AND (lag(min_flow, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0)
    OR (
    -- current row + next 2 rows –previous 2 rows  have a min(flow) > 0
    (lead(min_flow, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0         
    AND (lead(min_flow, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0 
    AND (lag(min_flow, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0
    AND (lag(min_flow, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0)
    OR (
    -- current row + next 1 row – previous 3 rows  have a min(flow) > 0
    (lead(min_flow, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0         
    AND (lag(min_flow, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0 
    AND (lag(min_flow, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0
    AND (lag(min_flow, 3) OVER (PARTITION BY group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date_)) > 0)
    )
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS test
FROM table
```

However, I was wondering if there is a better/more efficient way of doing it?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: If any of the answers solves the problem please check that one. Otherwise post comments explaining why they are not good enough.

Comment: @Clodoaldo: Hi, sorry for my late reply. I solved the problem and marked the answer accordingly. Many thanks for everyone's answers they have been very useful!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the difference between `row_number()` over all rows and over partition by postive / non_positive `min_flow` to determine groups of consecutive rows:

```
select 
    group_id,
    _date_,
    min_flow,
    (count(*) over w_diff > 4)::int test
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over w_all rn_all, 
        row_number() over w_pos rn_pos
    from a_table
    window 
        w_all as (order by _date_),
        w_pos as (partition by min_flow > 0 order by _date_)
    ) s
    window w_diff as (partition by rn_all- rn_pos)
    order by _date_;
```

The query to illustrate the method:

```
select 
    *,
    rn_all- rn_pos diff,
    (count(*) over w_diff > 4)::int test
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over w_all rn_all, 
        row_number() over w_pos rn_pos
    from a_table
    window 
        w_all as (order by _date_),
        w_pos as (partition by min_flow > 0 order by _date_)
    ) s
    window w_diff as (partition by rn_all- rn_pos)
    order by _date_;

 group_id |   _date_   | min_flow | rn_all | rn_pos | diff | test 
----------+------------+----------+--------+--------+------+------
        1 | 2012-02-01 |        0 |      1 |      1 |    0 |    0
        1 | 2012-02-02 |        0 |      2 |      2 |    0 |    0
        1 | 2012-02-03 |      1.5 |      3 |      1 |    2 |    1
        1 | 2012-02-04 |        1 |      4 |      2 |    2 |    1
        1 | 2012-02-05 |      0.7 |      5 |      3 |    2 |    1
        1 | 2012-02-06 |      0.8 |      6 |      4 |    2 |    1
        1 | 2012-02-07 |      1.2 |      7 |      5 |    2 |    1
        1 | 2012-02-08 |      1.5 |      8 |      6 |    2 |    1
        1 | 2012-02-09 |        0 |      9 |      3 |    6 |    0
        1 | 2012-02-10 |        0 |     10 |      4 |    6 |    0
        1 | 2012-02-11 |      0.9 |     11 |      7 |    4 |    0
        1 | 2012-02-12 |      1.2 |     12 |      8 |    4 |    0
        1 | 2012-02-13 |        0 |     13 |      5 |    8 |    0
        1 | 2012-02-14 |        0 |     14 |      6 |    8 |    0
(14 rows)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer! It has been very useful!! :) I added the condition min_flow!=0 to filter thoses cases at the begining where min_flow was 0 and they were more than 5: (count(*) over w_diff > 4 AND min_flow!=0)::int test  I also added group_id in the window function to differentiate by groups.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would consider using a nested query, in which you firstly look to see whether there have been five successive positive values in the *past* five days, with:

```
sum(case when min_flow > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
  over (partition by  group_id
        order by      group_id, _date_
        range between _date_ - '4 day'::Interval preceding
                  and _date_) count_of_positives_in_last_5_days
```

... and then look for the maximum of that value in the next five days.

```
max(count_of_positives_in_last_5_days)
  over (partition by  group_id
        order by      group_id, _date_
        range between _date_
                  and _date_ + '4 day'::Interval following) max_count_of_positives_in_last_5_days
```

If that maximum is 5, then return a 1, else a 0.

If you can do a SQLFiddle of the data then I might be able to explain that better, and test that it actually works :)

Comment: Hi David, many thanks for you help!! I have tried to implement it as it seems a very straightforward solution, but I cant make the the RANGE bit work (in the SUM part).... It says there is a syntaxis error with partenthesis just before "count_of_positives_in_last_5_days"... I don't understand why as parethesis are ok. have tried to replace "_date_" by "current row", but then I get "ERROR:  RANGE PRECEDING is only supported with UNBOUNDED"... I would like to understand why is not working, as I think it's a really good solution. Any idea? (I don't know how SQLFiddle work...sorry).

Comment: I read in several posts that apparently RANGE is not supported by postgres... replacing RANGE for ROW seems to work: SUM (case when min_flow> 0 then 1 else 0 end) OVER (partition by group_id ORDER BY group_id, _date ROWS between 4 PRECEDING AND 0 following) AS count_of_positives_in_last_5_days. The syntaxis seems to be a bit different though as it doesn't use '4 days':: interval... hope this is ok? This makes me wonder...what's the difference between ROWS and RANGE then? Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm could be that there are restrictions on the syntax in postgresql that stop this working

Answer (score 0):

Naive counting, assuming that the dates are unique per group_id. (

`(group_id, zdate)` is considered a candidate key)

```
SELECT m.*, EXISTS(
        SELECT 1 FROM meuk x
        WHERE x.group_id = m.group_id
        AND x.zdate >= m.zdate - '4 day'::interval
        AND x.zdate <= m.zdate
        AND x.min_flow > 0
        GROUP BY x.group_id
        HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
        ) AS valid_for_five_days
FROM meuk m
        ;
```

---

Result:

```
 group_id |   zdate    | min_flow | test | valid_for_five_days 
----------+------------+----------+------+---------------------
        1 | 2012-02-01 |        0 | f    | f
        1 | 2012-02-02 |        0 | f    | f
        1 | 2012-02-03 |      1.5 | t    | f
        1 | 2012-02-04 |        1 | t    | f
        1 | 2012-02-05 |      0.7 | t    | f
        1 | 2012-02-06 |      0.8 | t    | f
        1 | 2012-02-07 |      1.2 | t    | t
        1 | 2012-02-08 |      1.5 | t    | t
        1 | 2012-02-09 |        0 | f    | f
        1 | 2012-02-10 |        0 | f    | f
        1 | 2012-02-11 |      0.9 | f    | f
        1 | 2012-02-12 |      1.2 | f    | f
        1 | 2012-02-13 |        0 | f    | f
        1 | 2012-02-14 |        0 | f    | f
(14 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to use EXISTS but after a couple of hours running the query didn't finish ... Maybe I am doing something wrong...(or maybe is not a good idea using it when using several subqueries? In my case I have 4 subqueries nested)... but I am very grateful for introducing that command I didnt know! :)